# Are forwarding references always deduced as some kind of reference?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I think about forwarding references as part of perfect forwarding. I was trying to explain it to someone and realized I didn't know: Can it ever deduce `T&&` as some non-reference type?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename Expected>
void checkDeduction(auto&& x) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Expected, decltype(x)>);
}

int main() {
    checkDeduction<int&&>(1);
    const volatile int x = 0;
    checkDeduction<const volatile int&>(x);
    checkDeduction<const volatile int&&>(std::move(x)); // Weird, but whatever.   
    // Is there anything for which checkDeduction<int>(foo) will compile?
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cr8K1dsKa

I think the answer is "no", that it's always either an rvalue or lvalue reference.

I think this is because if `f` forwards to `g`:

```
decltype(auto) f(auto&& x) { return g(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)); }
```

it's not that `f` has the same signature as `g`, but rather that `f` is compiled with the value categories that the caller of `f` provides, so if `g` takes `int`, and you call `f(1)` then `f` gets an `int&&` and forwards that to `g`. At that call to `g`, the `int&&` decays to an `int`.

Comment: Forwarding references are references.

Comment: A reference type can never not be a reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver I mean, I know, but at the same time, definitions can be subtle.

Comment: This got closed as a duplicate. I don’t think it’s the same question. I’m not surprised that `const auto&&` is a const rvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

Plainly `T&&` is some kind of reference; the interesting question is whether `T` will always be deduced as a reference type.  The answer is **no**: if the argument is an lvalue of type `U`, `T` will be `U&`, but if it’s an rvalue, `T` will just be `U`.

There is a sort of missed opportunity here: the language could say that a **prvalue** is deduced as `U` and an **xvalue** is deduced as `U&&` (which would still collapse with the “outer” reference operator).  However, the judgment was that that distinction didn’t matter, at least not enough to justify creating additional template specializations everywhere.

It’s still possible to write `f<X&&>(…)` to **force** a forwarding reference’s template parameter to be an rvalue reference, although this wouldn’t usually accomplish anything.